# matching elements from one set to another using given metric

Tags: python, algorithm, matching

First, I'd like to say **I'm not looking for code, I'm looking for an algorithm**.

## Motivation:

I'm writing top-level testing of a complex real-time software system. It runs all software components (~20 processes, ~100 threads), sets up fake data sources (rtsp video sources) and feeds prepared data (video files) to the system, records system responses (events) and then stops the system after all prepared test data was sent.

As the test data is always the same, I expect tested system to provide correct responses (events) at correct times (from the start of the test).

I then compare generated responses (events) to expected events (manually prepared), which I expect to be all there, possibly with some small time variances which I would limit with some given `time-tolerance`, let's say 5 seconds.

Let's say the tested system is supposed to detect animals in 1500 seconds long video and I watched it and written down 5 animals and time when they appeared in video:

```
at   10s - a sparrow
at   20s - a cat
at   50s - a rabbit
at  100s - an owl
at 1000s - a bear
```

Based on that, I would then write `expected_events` set:

```
expected_events = [
    Event(10, 'sparrow'),
    Event(20, 'cat'),
    Event(50, 'rabbit'),
    Event(100, 'owl')
    Event(1000, 'bear')
]
```

And I want to be able to tell how well the real detected events (which will be affected by processor load, disk usage, network usage atd, as this is multiprocess system on real computer) *match* these `expected_eevents`.

Let's say the tested system returned:

```
detected_events = [
    Event(10.1, 'sparrow'),
    Event(19.5, 'cat'),
    Event(50.2, 'rabbit'),
    Event(99.3, 'owl')
    Event(1000.2, 'bear')
]
```

Which I would evaluate as correct, 100% match with expected events, all events are present and time differences are below `time-tolerance`:

```
matches = [
    {'name': 'sparrow', 'detected': 10.1,   'expected': 10,   'time-diff': 0.1},
    {'name': 'cat',     'detected': 19.5,   'expected': 20,   'time-diff': 0.5},
    {'name': 'rabbit',  'detected': 50.2,   'expected': 50,   'time-diff': 0.2},
    {'name': 'owl',     'detected': 99.3,   'expected': 100,  'time-diff': 0.7},
    {'name': 'bear',    'detected': 1000.2, 'expected': 1000, 'time-diff': 0.2},
]
```

If the tested system returned:

```
detected_events = [
    Event(10.1, 'sparrow'),
    Event(50.2, 'rabbit'),
    Event(99.3, 'owl')
    Event(1010.5, 'bear')
]
```

which I would expect could result in matches like this:

```
raw_matches = [
    {'name': 'sparrow', 'detected': 10.1,   'expected': 10,   'time-diff': 0.1},
    {'name': 'cat',     'detected': None,   'expected': 20,   'time-diff': None},
    {'name': 'rabbit',  'detected': 50.2,   'expected': 50,   'time-diff': 0.2},
    {'name': 'owl',     'detected': 99.3,   'expected': 100,  'time-diff': 0.7},
    {'name': 'bear',    'detected': 1010.5, 'expected': 1000, 'time-diff': 10.52},
]

pruned_matches = [
    {'name': 'sparrow', 'detected': 10.1,   'expected': 10,   'time-diff': 0.1},
    {'name': 'rabbit',  'detected': 50.2,   'expected': 50,   'time-diff': 0.2},
    {'name': 'owl',     'detected': 99.3,   'expected': 100,  'time-diff': 0.7},
]
```

I would see this as fail, because:

- it didn't detected a cat
- bear was detected 10.5 seconds too late
- therefore only 3 out of 5 was really matched and result should be 60% match

So I what I need is a method for evaluating `detected_events` against `expected_events` to be able to evaluate how good the tested system works.

## Simplyfication

Because matching *event types* is essential to the problem and can be done as matching for every event type separately, I'll do following simplyfications:

- all events are the same - i.e. only the time of the event is important and therefore event will be represented only by the timestamp
- timestamp will be `int` to make it easier to read

## What do I consider to be a "good" match:

As many of you pointed out in comments, I actually don't have metric for evaluating final matching beyond dismissing matches with time difference > `time-tolerance`.
This makes it a bit harder, but I think it's intuitive - I know what should happen at which time, and I compare that to actual events and I'll try to match them as good as is possible to make sure:

- as many expected events are matched as possible
- each `detected_event` matching `expected_event` must happen at the same time with given time tolerance.

So this I would consider "correct" matches (with 5 second time tolerance):

```
                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 20]  =>        {'expected': 10,    'detected': 10},
detected_events = [10, 20]            {'expected': 20,    'detected': 20},
                                  ]

                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 20]  =>        {'expected': 10,    'detected': 15},
detected_events = [15, 25]            {'expected': 20,    'detected': 25},
                                  ]

                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 20]  =>        {'expected': 10,    'detected':  5},
detected_events = [ 5, 15]            {'expected': 20,    'detected': 15},
                                  ]

                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 11]  =>        {'expected': 10,    'detected': 11},
detected_events = [11, 12]            {'expected': 11,    'detected': 12},
                                  ]


                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 20]  =>        {'expected': 10,    'detected': 10},
detected_events = [10, 26]        ]

expected_events = [10, 20]  =>    matches = []
detected_events = [ 4, 26]

                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 20, 30] =>     {'expected': 20,    'detected': 17},
detected_events = [17, 24]        ]
```

This I would consider "bad" matches (i.e. this is **not how I want it to work**):

```
                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 20]  =>        {'expected': 20,    'detected': 15},
detected_events = [15, 25]        ]
# matched only 1 events even though it's possible to match 2

                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 11]  =>        {'expected': 11,    'detected': 11},
detected_events = [11, 12]        ]
# matched only 1 events even though it's possible to match 2


                                  matches = [
expected_events = [10, 20]  =>        {'expected': 10,    'detected': 4},
detected_events = [ 4, 26]            {'expected': 20,    'detected': 26},
                                  ]
# should not match anything, time differences > 5sec
```

## Pseudocode / What I tried:

Code should look something like this:

```
expected_events = [10, 20, 50, 100, 1000] # times in second
detected_events = [11, 18, 51,      1001]

def metric(ev1, ev2):
    return abs(ev1 - ev2)

matches = match_events(expected_events, detected_events, metric, tolerance=5)
```

1. Simple, naive approach - start from best match

   I tried extremely simple approach:

   - product of (expected_events, detected_events)
   - compute time difference
   - filter matches with time difference greater than given tolerance
   - sort matches by time difference
   - start matching from first matches and discard "conflicts" (i.e. latter matches using same elements)

   This works for simple cases, but I run into a problem when events are "shifted":

   ```
    expected_events = [10, 11]
    detected_events = [11, 12]
   ```

   Now I get:

   ```
    [
        {'expected': 11,    'detected': 11},
    ]
   ```

   While I want to have:

   ```
    [
        {'expected': 10,    'detected': 11},
        {'expected': 11,    'detected': 12},
    ]
   ```
2. Brute force - permutations

   Then I tried brute force:

   - product of (expected_events, detected_events)
   - compute time difference
   - filter matches with time difference greater than given tolerance
   - create all possible permutations of given matches
   - for each permutation, start matching from first matches and discard "conflicts" (i.e. latter matches using same elements)
   - compute lengths of all those matchings
   - keep only those with maximal length
   - select matching with min(sort by sum of all time differences)

   This works, but as you may have expected, it's too slow for anything longer than few elements. (I hoped to make it work using lazy evaluation, but couldn't make it work).

## Question:

What would be a correct algorithm for such matching?
It seems to me this may be already *solved problem* - but I don't know what to search for.

---

It *is* a *solved problem* - **assignment problem** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem - thanks to Yossi Levi!

Comment: The problem seems underspecified. Suppose you were matching [2,3,4] with [3,4,9]. Would it be better to just match 2-2,3-3, or to match 2-3, 3-4, 4-9? What’s your objective function?

Comment: Also, do you really want to treat the metric as a black box, or will you assume anything about its properties?

Comment: Sequential best-match with low-cost adjustments can solve much of the empirical problems, but let's consider a dual-error situation a bit more separated than your 10/11/12 case: `[2, 8, 9]` and `[3, 4, 8]`  It *looks* as if you want an answer of `2-3, 8-8`, but you've given us nothing to balance quantity of coverage versus time difference.  Your given approach is a very good start, except for the efficiency, but we need a problem specification to help you advance.

Comment: algorithm steps:
- pad the smaller list with don't care values - just to make sure dimensions agreed
- create similarity matrix by decreasing each element of one list to element in other list, let's define the matrix as S.
*clarification: S[i,j] refer to the difference between i'th element from list A to j'th element in list B*
lets define the limitation value as L
- create binary matrix B in which every element that satisfy the condition limitation is 1, otherwise it 0 (B = S<L)
- find the maximum value of TRACE for all the permutations of the columns (N!)

Comment: really wanted this answer to be an answer and not comment, spent time for styling and examples, to make it clear.

Comment: @Sneftel sorry, I'll try to update the question, but simply - objective is to tell how well some real-time process output matches expected output. I may have oversimplyfied.. As for metric - it's just a time difference in this question, but in reality there is event "type" match also, but I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: No, I mean, what is the *objective function*. You want to pick one of many potential outputs -- what specific rules do you use to rank two potential outputs relative to each other?

Comment: @Sneftel - i updated the question - I realized I *don't* have objective function - so I added a bunch of examples of how I want it to work and what I would consider correct... I realize now I probably should not have asked the question as it's now even less well specified than it was before..

Comment: @Prune, in your case (`[2, 8, 9] + [3, 4, 8]`) I would want matches to be `[2-3, 8-8]` if max.time difference tolerance would be > 4. If it would be 5sec or more, I would want match all: `[2-3, 8-4, 9-8]`. I added some more description and examples, but soon I realized it's poorly specified (because all my speficication is something like: "tell us how well the system performs compared to expected output"). Sorry :(

Comment: @YossiLevi make it into an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will follow your asking, and provide a non-programming approach, but only logical (semi-mathematical) approach as I see it.

Algorithm steps:

- lets define the threshold as `T`
- pad the smaller list with don't care values (None for example) - just to make sure the dimension agreed
- create similarity matrix by take absolute value of decreasing each element of one list to element in other list, let's define the matrix as S.

*clarification: S[i,j] refer to the difference between i'th element from list A to j'th element in list B*

- create binary matrix B in which every element that satisfy the threshold critirea is 1, otherwise it 0 (MATLAB-> B=S<L)

for example:

```
       0 0 0
    
B =    0 1 1
    
       1 0 0
```

saying X dimension represent list A and Y represent list B then:

```
B[2] === A[2]
B[2] === A[3]
B[3] === A[1] (=== means that two elements satisfy the criteria of similarity)
```

Now - the question becomes more mathematical, in order to find the best match, you can use one of the following suggestions:

**brute force (less elegant approach in my opinion):**

- choose element which is 1 (among non marked rows and columns)
- mark his entire column and row as marked
- keep choose another 1 until there aren't legal places and sum it up to `score`
- iteratively do it for all options and choose the one with the highest `score`

**more elegant approach:**

- iterate over all permutations of columns (for B matrix)
- if Trace or opposite-diagonal equals to len(A) then finish (found matching for all elements)
- choose the permutation with highest TRACE (or the opposite diagonal)
  number of permutations in worst case are of-course N! (which N is the dimension of B)

**Best approach:**

While searching over the net on how to find the maximum Trace of matrix when only columns swapping allowed I ran into [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) (pay attention please to *Example* and *Matrix interpretation* sections).
moreover, I found implementation of it in [PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/hungarian-algorithm/).

As the documentation says - the algorithm is trying to find the **minimum** Trace over all possible permutations of matrix - so just invole with `-B` as argument instead.

**overall example (with more elegant approach as last step):**

```
A = [1,5,7]
B = [6,6,2]

T = 2

S = 
5 5 1 
1 1 3
1 1 5

B = 
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 0

permutations of columns:

1- 
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 0

Trace = 1
other-diagonal = 3

Done -- > no need for more permutations because len(other-diagonal) == 3
A[1] =1 === B[3] =2
A[2] =5 === B[2] =6
A[3] =7 === B[1] =6
```

feel free to ask, or give any insights that you might have

Answer (score 0):

I just found out there is pretty good implementation of "Hungarian algorithm" (assignment problem) in scipy python package:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html

Example (for `expected`, `detected`, `metric` see the question's example code):

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

...

def match_events(expected, detected, metric, tolerance=5):
    # some arbitrary large value used to prevent impossible matches
    dont_match = 1000 * tolerance

    def modified_metric(e, d):
        dt = metric(e, d)
        return dt if dt <= tolerance else dont_match

    cost_matrix = [
        [
            modified_metric(exp, det)
            for det in detected
        ]
        for exp in expected
    ]
    row_idx, col_idx = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
    for e_idx, d_idx in zip(row_idx, col_idx):
        dt = cost_matrix[e_idx][d_idx]
        if dt <= time_tolerance:
            yield (expected[e_idx], detected[d_idx], dt)
```

It's not very elegant, because I had to somehow limit matches to `tolerance`, but Hungarian algorithm works only on matrix of all possible combinations, so I use `dont_match` value to mark those cases.